# ZonedDateTime format- Elasticsearch index mapping

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, mapping, zoneddatetime, datetimeformatter

I am trying to specify the format of my date in my Elasticsearch index mapping like this documentation states: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

I have a date in this format: `2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z[UTC]`. How would I turn this into a format like `YYYY-MM-DD...`? Specifically, how to represent the `[UTC]` part at the end?

Currently I have the following mapping, I'm getting the error below, so I am trying to specify the format of the date to see if that works. Thanks!

```
    "createdTimeStamp": {
      "type": "date"
    },
```

```
Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=failed to parse field [createdTimeStamp] of type [date] in document with id 'testId1'.

Preview of field's value: '{offset={totalSeconds=0, rules={fixedOffset=true, transitionRules=[], transitions=[]}, id=Z}, year=2015, dayOfYear=1, nano=0, chronology={calendarType=iso8601, id=ISO}, minute=10, second=30, dayOfWeek=THURSDAY, month=JANUARY, hour=12, zone={totalSeconds=0, rules={fixedOffset=true, transitionRules=[], transitions=[]}, id=Z}, dayOfMonth=1, monthValue=1}']];

nested: ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_state_exception, reason=Can't get text on a START_OBJECT at 1:72]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not have expertise in Elasticsearch. However, the following solution should help you resolve your issue.

You can mention the format, `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX['['z']']` as shown in the example on the [documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z[UTC]";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX['['z']']");

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, formatter);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, formatter);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z[UTC]
2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z
```

The `['['z']']` at the end of the format makes `'['z']'` [optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) where `[` and `]` are literals while `z` specifies the time-zone.

### Some useful information:

Your date-time string has `Z[UTC]` at the end where `Z` is an important letter specifying `Zulu` date-time which is nothing but `UTC` date-time. In other words, your date-time represents a date-time in `UTC`. The `ZonedDateTime` can parse it without requiring any formatter.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z[UTC]";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z[UTC]
```

However, it looks like Elasticsearch does not use `ZonedDateTime` to parse the date-time strings. The [documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) mentions that the default format is either [`strict_date_optional_time`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html#strict-date-time) or `epoch_millis` as quoted below:

> Date formats can be customised, but if no format is specified then it
> uses the default:
>
> "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"

So, in order to conform to the default format, an alternative way is to get rid of `[UTC]` from the end of your date-time string. After this change, the string can be parsed by all of `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime`, and `Instant` without requiring any formatter.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z[UTC]";
        strDateTime = strDateTime.substring(0, strDateTime.indexOf('['));
        System.out.println("Trimmed date-time string: " + strDateTime);

        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(odt);

        Instant instant = Instant.parse(strDateTime);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Trimmed date-time string: 2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z
2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z
2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z
2020-10-29T05:36:06.143Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to escape `Z` itself -- it's a symbol that [represents zone offsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and is not a valid value in and of itself.

```
PUT myindex/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "createdTimeStamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z[UTC]'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you know *for sure* that all the incoming values will be in UTC, you can leave the above as-is. This'll escape that `[UTC]` part too.

If you expect multiple time zones, you can use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z['z']'` instead -- the lowercase `z` will parse the incoming time zone for you and store the date internally in UTC but with an offset. That way, you'll only have escaped the uppercase `Z` for the reasons described above.